# How do I login with with the user credentials in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a simple login and logout app in Django.

I wrote two views one for login and another for register.

Register view is working as expected. But login view is causing issues.

I'm using `form.is_valid()` in login view. That is where the issue is arising. If I print the form in else block, it is saying **A user with that username already exists**. This is happening even before trying to authenticate the user. Some one help me with this.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from notes.forms import UserForm

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse("Logged in")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong creds")
        else:
            print(form)
            return HttpResponse("else of is_valid()")

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'register.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            existing = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            if existing:
                return HttpResponse('Username is already taken')
            else:
                User.objects.create(username=username, password = password, email=email)
                return HttpResponse("User created with "+ username +" username")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from notes.models import Note
from django import forms


class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Comment: A `UserForm` is a `ModelForm` on `User` (I presume) used to *create* new `User`s, and it thus also checks if the login name already exists.

Comment: I already have that too. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `form.is_valid()` call will validate the form, this is done through [several steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation). Depending on the fields of the model, it thus also checks the *uniqness* of the data.

The [**`User`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) model has a uniqness constraint on the `username`, hence the `UserForm` can only be valid, if the `username` is not yet taken, or when the form contains a instance that is already stored in the database.

I therefore think that it might be better to create a `LoginForm`, like Django does with an [**`AuthenticationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) [[GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1b49b792e9f0e6a5ae22f49f75586847e7e183bf/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L156). For example:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
```